# Spring:AOP: Cannot handle Exception while using Proxy

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I am unable to trap exceptions before they are written to the console/log.

I have the following in the spring-configuration.

```
<bean id="loggingTxAdvice" class="com.acme.LoggingEngine"/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<aop:spring-configured/>

<aop:config>

<aop:advisor id="loggingTxService" advice-ref="loggingTxAdvice" pointcut="execution(* uk.co.acme.service.*.*(..))" />

<aop:advisor id="loggingTxDao" advice-ref="loggingTxAdvice" pointcut="execution(* uk.co.acme.dao.*.*(..))" />

<aop:advisor id="loggingTxSecurity" advice-ref="loggingTxAdvice"  pointcut="execution(* uk.co.acme.security.*(..))" />

</aop:config>
```

Now I have

```
AcmeAction.doSomething(){
    try{
       AcemeService.doService():

     }catch(FunctionalException fe){
       LogHelper.logConditionally...
     } 
}

AcmeService{

  doService() throws FunctionalException{
     AcmeDao.doDao();
  }

}

AcmeDao{

  doDAO() throws FunctionalException{
     if(someCondition){
         throw new FunctionalException();

      }

}
```

The problem is, before it reaches **LogHelper.logConditionally** of **AcmeAction.doSomething** a loads of stack traces are printed to the log/console.

I don't need those exceptions to the thrown to the console, rather I need to log them conditionally, that's why I handle them using LogHelper.logConditionally.

I even have a condition in the com.acme.LoggingEngine

```
class com.acme.LoggingEngine implements MethodInterceptor, ThrowsAdvice, Serializable {

    public void afterThrowing(Method m, Object[] args, Object target, Throwable ex) {
       ......
     if (ex instanceof FunctionalException) {
        LogHelper.logConditionally(....);
     } 
        .......
}
```

**The above code works and prints only conditionally information, but still a load of stacktraces are printed (Which is what I am trying to suppress), but never works.
Why is so? How could I handle this? Any help would be highly appreciated.**

**stack trace**

```
at uk.co.acme.AcmeDAO.getQuote(AcmeDAO.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at uk.co.acme..util.LoggingEngine.invoke(LoggingEngine.java:72)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy108.getQuote(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.acme.AcmeService.getQuote
```

**Additional Information**

After stepping into the code, I see that ThrowsAdviceInterceptor#invoke is re-throwing, which is why the exception is printing. How do I prevent ThrowsAdviceInterceptor from doing it? as I already got my LoggingInterceptor(LoggingEngine) ?

Comment: could you post stack trace from start

Comment: It looks good to me in general, however I can't see where do you define `loggingTxAdvice`.

Comment: @Atul that's from the start.

Comment: @Balint Bako - Sorry that was lost during the formatting (Which is now back). Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you use <tx:advice id="loggingTxAdvice"> and not a simple bean?

Comment: I just tried to wrap a try catch around the  

 **public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation)**  

It's getting there but, still prints the stack trace which is very very strange.

Comment: @ Balint Bako - not really, we define the bean and pass it to the **advice-ref="bean-id"**

Comment: After stepping into the code, I see that ThrowsAdviceInterceptor#invoke is re-throwing, which is why the exception is printing. How do I prevent ThrowsAdviceInterceptor from doing it? as I already got my LoggingInterceptor(LoggingEngine) ?

Comment: I can't see if the exception is FunctionalException or not, you should catch Throwable maybe.

Comment: Guys absolutely sorry, the issue was inside my code in the LogHelper.logConditionally. I fixed that issue and it all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stepping into the code, I found that the issue was inside my code:

```
LogHelper.logConditionally
```

It was printing error instead of warn.

Thanks for all the comments.